# Dealing with Duplicate Dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, duplicates, time-series

The problem is that I have a large data set with missing date entries and also duplicates. I can't drop any of them so, I need to add the missing dates and have the corresponding columns be NaN.
Here's a sample code of it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'timestamps': pd.to_datetime(
    ['2016-11-15 1:00','2016-11-16 2:00','2016-11-16 3:00','2016-11-18 4:00']),
'values':['a','b','c','d']})
 df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamps']).floor('D')

 all_days = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='D')
```

While searching I found that we shouldn't go with `df.reindex()` as it can't handle duplicates. So the other solution is to use
     `df.loc[all_days]` but, everytime I use it as 
    `df.loc[all_days] = [0,0]` all it says is that my missing date, which I need to add to the dataframe, is not in the index.

It should go from this:

```
           timestamps             values
2016-11-15  "2016-11-15 01:00:00"  a
2016-11-16  "2016-11-16 02:00:00"  b
2016-11-16  "2016-11-16 03:00:00"  c
2016-11-18  "2016-11-18 04:00:00"  d`
```

To this:

```
timestamps             values
2016-11-15  "2016-11-15 01:00:00"  a
2016-11-16  "2016-11-16 02:00:00"  b
2016-11-16  "2016-11-16 03:00:00"  c 
2016-11-17  NaN                    NaN
2016-11-18  "2016-11-18 04:00:00"  d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the `all_days` to a dataframe, then do an outer join with `df`, then drop the new unnecessary columns:

```
new_df = df.join(all_days.to_frame(), how='outer').drop(0,1)

>>> new_df
                    timestamps values
2016-11-15 2016-11-15 01:00:00      a
2016-11-16 2016-11-16 02:00:00      b
2016-11-16 2016-11-16 03:00:00      c
2016-11-17                 NaT    NaN
2016-11-18 2016-11-18 04:00:00      d
```

Comment: Nice sacul.  Very nice using merge.

Comment: Thanks @ScottBoston! But I realized it's much more succinct to use `join` instead of `merge` (though both should work)